# How to prove this vector identity?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, sobolev-spaces, electromagnetism

I've seen this vector identity from the book[1] in page 89,
$$ (\nabla p)\times\nu =0,\ \text{on}\ \partial\Omega,$$
where $\nu $ is the outer normal vector of $\partial \Omega$, $ p \in H_0^1(\Omega).$
I try to calculate directly $(\nabla p)\times \nu =(\nu_3\partial_2 p-\nu_2\partial_3 p,\nu_1\partial_3 p-\nu_3\partial_1 p,\nu_2\partial_1 p-\nu_1\partial_2 p)^T,$ but I don't know how to show it equals $0$.

[1] Monk, Peter, Finite Element Methods for Maxwell's Equations (Oxford, 2003; online edn, Oxford Academic, 1 Sept. 2007)

Comment: This depends on the context. For general $p$ this is certainly false.

Answer (score 0):

Also, $(\nabla p)\times \nu=|\nabla p ||\nu|\sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.  For the cross product to be zero the two vectors must be parallel.  You must show that $\nabla p$ is parallel to $\nu$

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. If you do not have sufficieint reputation to comment, then consider leaving a detailed answer that will increase your reputation.

Comment: On $\partial \Omega, p=0$. 
The gradient $\nabla p$ is perpendicular to the level sets of  $p $(the level sets are surfaces where $p$ is constant).
The outer normal vector $ν$ is also perpendicular to the boundary.

Comment: You must do more work to define level sets and $\nabla p$ on the boundary for functions in Sobolev spaces, which are not functions, but equivalence classes of integrable functions.